# Javascript regular expression pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me to figure what's wrong with my pattern?

this is my text: sid='206' x='34.8395' y='32.1178'>×2 (206)

```
var regex = new RegExp("/x=\'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\' y=\'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\'/");

var match;
do {
    match = regex.exec(text);
    if (match) {
        console.log(match[1], match[2], match[3], match[4]);
    }
} while (match);
```

Comment: Tip, you can use \d as shorthand for [0-9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no delimiters in `RegExp` constructor.

You can use this regex:

```
var re = /x='(\d+\.\d+)' +y='(\d+\.\d+)'/g; 
var str = "sid=\'206' x='34.8395' y='32.1178'>×2 (206)";

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
   console.log(match[1], match[2]);
}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH1fC9/3)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing any capturing groups.  In RegEx these are groups between `()`  If you rewrite it like this:

```
x=\'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\' y=\'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\'
```

Then you an get the `x` and `y` with match[1](http://regex101.com/r/aH9rW9/1) and match[2]

Here is a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aH9rW9/1)